# Pass PHP array to Javascript inside a string variable (HTML Injection)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, undefined

I know this is a common question, but I am struggling with this!

I'm creating the HTML from a PHP file, so every HTML and Javascript is being passed as a variable ($string). This is some of my code, where I need to pass the values of $objects_list to the javascript variable objects_list:

```
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">
                function open_project(id)
                {
                    var objects_list = '. json_encode($objects_list) .';
                    console.log(objects_list.lenght);
                }
            </script>';
```

Thing is, that console.log prints *undefined*. How can I solve this?
If I remove the json_encode I get an error for converting array to string.

---

EDIT:

Just noticed, if I `console.log(objects_list[5]`, by example, it prints the correct value so the problem is actually with the `objects_list.lenght` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake:

```
console.log(objects_list.lenght);
```

Should be

```
console.log(objects_list.length);
```

Comment: Oh God, that was dumb. Thanks a lot mate.